# Correct best-fit algorithm for bin packing?

Tags: c#, bin-packing

I have the following numbers
6,8,9,4,3,2,10,7,14,12,6,2,3,1,10,11,13,5

I wish to know the correct way to implement the best-fit 1D Bin packing algorithm for these.
Because in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2P1TzKKWOI&feature=related they are solving it differently than in my mind so i don't know the correct answer.

My Solution, First come first serve, so:

- Bin #1: 6,8,2
- Bin #2: 9,4,3
- Bin #3: 3,10,1
- Bin #4: 7,6
- Bin #5: 14,2
- Bin #6: 12
- Bin #7: 10
- Bin #8: 11,5
- Bin #9: 13

Their Solution, i guess they "pair" the suitable numbers together, so it goes like:

- Bin #1: 6,10
- Bin #2: 9,7
- Bin #3: 14,2
- Bin #4: 12,4
- Bin #5: 14,2
- Bin #6: 13,3
- Bin #7: 8,6,2
- Bin #8: 10,5,1
- Bin #9: 11,3

Which one is correct?

Comment: There isn't enough information for a suitable answer here, their numbers are more evenly distributed though, which could be classed as "better", and they don't leave as much empty space in their used bins, which could also be classed as "better". Your solution is also missing 2 numbers.

Comment: i didn't notice the missing 2 numbers.
Theirs is definitely better but at the same time requires knowing all the numbers in advance

@dpott197 sorry didn't know

Comment: [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e4560) are some images explaining First Fit and First Fit Decreasing and a short explanation of Best Fit (but no image yet :(). Maybe it helps.

Comment: FWIW only 8 bins are required. e.g. [14 2][13 3][12 4][11 5][10 6][10 6][9 3 2 1][8 7]

Answer (score 3):

I've attached the algorithm at the end of my comment.

@AngelicCore, I think the fundamental difference between your solution and the one in the video is that your solution is an "on-line" solution and the one in the video is an "off-line" solution.

Off-line bin packing assumes that the packer has perfect information about each item and has time to arrange them in any order he or she would like. Consider a warehouse with a staging area for shipping. All the cases can be stacked, palletized, and re-ordered as needed until it is ready to be shipped.

On-line bin packing is done "on-the-fly" often on a first-in-first-out basis (FIFO). Imagine you are receiving cases from incoming trucks unto a conveyor belt. The material handling equipment quickly re-directs all cases to a fleet of outgoing trucks.

Additional Notes

The bin capacity is given at 16. (14+13+12+11+10+10+9+8+7+6+6+5­+4+3+3+2+2+1)/16 = 126/16 ~ 7.87 => ceiling(7.87) = 8 minimum
bins are the lower bound.

### Algorithm

#### Best-Fit Heuristic

This heuristic attempts to create the fullest bin possible each time an item is assigned. Again, all unfull bins are kept open. It places the next item j in the bin whose current contents are largest, but do not exceed Q − qj (so the item fits). If it does not fit in any bin, a new bin is opened.

Initialization :

Given a list of item weights L = {q1, q2, ..., qn}.

Place item1 in bin1 and remove from L. Letj=2,m=1.

Iterations :

1. Find the bin i whose remaining capacity is minimum but greater than qj (if Si are the items in bin i, Q −  qk is the remaining capacity of bin i), and place j in k∈Sii. If j does not fit in any bin, open a new bin and number it m + 1, place j in bin m + 1 and let m = m + 1.
2. Remove item j from L. Let j = j + 1.
3. While items remain in L, repeat from Step 1.